# Running C++ program using hash_map and unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I know C++ program containing unordered_map can be run using 'g++ -std=c++0x filename' but same program if made using hash_map shows an error? What change is needed to be done?

Comment: I would help if you posted the error...

Comment: or the code... or tell us where this hash_map is from...

Comment: Use `std::unordered_map`. `hash_map` is not a member of the standard library.

Comment: There is no such class `hash_map` in the standard library. You have manually include it, both the header files and linking with it. And if it's not on your computer, you have to install it from somewhere first.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am using like #include <hash_map> std::hash_map<int, int> occur;

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using `std::unordered_map`, since that's standard. `hash_map` was a container from the STL, a widely-used precursor to the standard C++ library, but was not included in the 1998 standard library. It was renamed to `unordered_map` for inclusion in the 2011 standard library, to avoid compatibility problems with older non-standard implementations.

If you really want to use the old STL `hash_map` for some reason, then GCC supplies it in `<backward/hash_map>`, in `namespace __gnu_cxx`.

Alternatively, you could get the STL from http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html. Then you would include `<hash_map>`and use `hash_map` in the global namespace.

Comment: Yeah. It would be better off using std::unordered_map and it is working perfectly fine. I just wanted to know why hash_map wasn't working.